# Input filtering and protection for instrumentation amplifier (2x ADA4528)

Tags: amplifier, adc, filter

I'm currently trying to measure the load cell output using AD's circuit note CN-0216 "Precision Weigh Scale Design Using the AD7791 24-Bit Sigma-Delta ADC with External ADA4528-1 Zero-Drift Amplifiers". The circuit works well, but my implementation is picking too much noise from sensor cable and body and even gets "ADC_ERROR" state if I switch on some heavy AC load near it. Beside that op amps' noninverting inputs are connected directly to the connector and are exposed to ESD without any resistors limiting current through internal protective diodes. So I want to implement an additional filtering/protective stage like on the picture below. If I'm not mistaken, the general rule is to choose CF2 = CF1/10. I know that adding RF resistors will degrade the noise performance of the circuit due to increased source resistance, but now noise pickup and lack of protection are much greater issues. So, can you please recommend the exact values for filter components, taking into consideration all the trade-offs in this schematics. The update rate of the ADC is 16Hz and signal frequency is less than 1 Hz. I also wonder why there is no such filter in AD's original circuit? Even without RF resistors CF1 and CF2 would form a low-pass filter with load cell output impedance, so why not to add them?
[image]

Comment: Decide on CMRR (f) and tolerances of RC then decide on    Break point for each . Eg 10 Hz or …. Are shielded pairs used? Where is gnd on shield? These matter!

Comment: If you don’t want to understand it, just copy the design of an ESD protected EEG amp which has similar requirements. But common part tolerances (CF1,Rg) don’t matter for CMRR like each polarity parts. 1% RC error raises CMRR to -40 dB for each error.  So, correct on <=1/10 rule

Comment: The caps might filter, but aren't going to offer enough protection to merit calling it "protection".